Determining a subject or object: what is the subject or object in this sentence "Has the door been fixed yet?"
I am a native English speaker, and have not formally learnt or done deep analysis of English grammar rules. I am now learning German, and a resource I am using uses English sentences and the idea of "subjects" and "objects" of a sentence to teach the Nominative and Accusative cases. The way they, and pretty much all German resources explain it is: the "subject" is the person or thing (ie a noun) that does the verb, and the "object" is the thing that is "verbed" (or the person or thing that the verb acts on).
In the exercises, one sentence says "Has the door been fixed yet?", and the answer says "door" is the subject, but I thought it is the object and that there is no subject in this sentence, because the "door" is, by their description and definition, being "verbed" (it is being "fixed"), and no person who does the fixing is mentioned (ie the subject doing the fixing could be you, me, some third party handyman; whoever it is, they are not mentioned).
So my question is: maybe this (the object is the thing being verbed) is not a foolproof way to identify the object of a sentence, but why is "door" the subject? is there a better way to identify the subject and object of a sentence? Can someone give a one-size-fits-all general rule for identifying the subject and object of a sentence?
Other examples I can think of would be something like "The cake was made without an oven." and I would say, based on the previous rule, that "cake" is the object since it was the one being verbed/made and again, no subject is given.

For questions, make it a statement and you will see: The door has already been fixed.

The door is the passive subject. The object is buried within the verb. 'Has the door been given a fix, yet ?' Up-voted +1, because you are working it out, in concepts.


The workman (S) has fixed the door (O).  In a passive construction what was the object now becomes the subject 2. The door (S) has been fixed [by the workman]. 3. Has the door (S) been fixed? The focus switches from the Agent i.e the person doing the action, to the receiver of the action. Often passive constructions omit the Agent because it is implied, unnecessary or unknown.


Either this question should be moved to ELL or an explanation should be made in very simple terms. I would post one that is understandable for this OP by using the simplest terms, but then, alas it wouldn't fly with the honchos.

Are you suggesting the Question has to do with formally learning or deep analysis of English?
Can you see an interpretation under which 'the door' would not be the subject?

@RobbieGoodwin Not sure which "question" you are referring to or what you are trying to ask but to clarify, I am trying to use this method to pick out the subject in English exacmple sentences, in order to learn a foreign language as per the recommended method.

Before anything else, which 'recommended method…' is this 'per'? Does that method deny, part of the definition of a sentence in English is that it has a subject?

If you accept that basic concept, how could any word but 'door' be the subject… or, come to that, an object?
If you reject that basic concept, how can you explain that?

@ishtar You wrote, then deleted, 'I think this is the simplest explanation for a beginner. I can talk about the VP-internal subject hypothesis and subject-to-subject raising, but I don't think that would benefit anyone here.'  But ELU isn't intended for beginners; linguists might feel insulted by the comment in the second sentence. Raising has certainly been covered on ELU.

Syntax ≠ Semantics
The sentences that are bothering you are passive ones. In passive sentences, the semantic agent and patient exchange their grammatical roles of subject and object without this altering who's acting on what. The grammar changes, including for agreement, but the semantics do not.
In English, you cannot not have a subject: every independent clause always has a grammatical subject. This is such a strong requirement that we sometimes have to use placeholders for this, such as it as in It is raining.
In Has the door been fixed yet? the subject is the singular noun phrase the door, which in turn governs the agreement of the finite verb, which is has in has been fixed. It does not lack a grammatical subject, for it cannot. You just don't know who the agent  responsible for that fixing may have been. These are not the same concept.
You've confused semantic roles such as agent and patient with syntactic roles (also called grammatical roles) such as subject and object. These are different things altogether.  Syntax is one thing, but semantics are another.
For grammatical matters such as morphology and agreement, you need to pay attention to the grammatical roles that various constituents play in the grammar. Semantic roles almost never play any part in this.

@Ihavemanyquestions To amplify: "Syntax is one thing, but semantics are another": That means that semantics can have equivalents in another language, as long as cultural barriers don't interfere; you can map "idea to idea." But the tools to express those ideas, the syntax, might be different.

The business. Small niggle: "In passive sentences, the semantic agent and patient exchange their grammatical roles of subject and object" <--Not quite. The semantic patient becomes the subject, but the agent, if there is one, either a) disappears (as in OP's example) or b) becomes the object of a preposition - more specifically of by.

@Araucaria-Him True. I'll try to get to an edit later today.

Thank you for the explanation, as I said, I've never deeply studied English grammar and the idea of a "patient" and "agent" is new to me, will look all those things up tomorrow. Thanks for the edit too - some of the keys on my keyboard don't work all that well.

@Ihavemanyquestions it may be easier to grasp if you use personal pronouns and keep in mind that I, he, she, we, and they are subject pronouns while me, him, her, us, and them are object pronouns.  He fed us (active); we were fed by him (passive).  Two ways of describing the same action, but differing in case.  A related issue is that the verb to be doesn't take an object but rather (using the terminology I learned in fourth grade) a predicate noun or adjective -- "be" isn't an action but describes state.  She is a teacher.  He used to be industrious.  The door has been fixed.

Thank you everyone. I'm leaving a short summary here for future reference: Grammatical "agents" and "patients" (something I've not learnt before in grade school or otherwise) are semantic roles and usually, but not always, the subject and object respectively. "To be" or the state of being, is the syntactic subject and not an object, even when a semantic agent is not present in the sentence. "The door/my keyboard/coffee table has been fixed (the state of being repaired)." Question: in the second link above, what is "Marge"? Object? Indirect object? Something else?

@Ihavemanyquestions Maybe this will help: Grammar is about building materials and the structures they occur in, not meaning (or not directly, anyway). Now, the words that make up sentences don't  just occur in a sequence like beads on a necklace, but are made up of clumps/chunks of words. They are grouped into phrases (including special phrases called 'clauses'). At sentence level, the various jobs that are required to be done are carried out by chunks of words (even where one of those chunks is made up of just one word. The two most basic basic jobs in a canonical sentence are the Subject ...

@Ihavemanyquestions ... and the Predicate (a canonical sentence is just one where things haven't been messed about with very much). Within the Predicate, the two most basic jobs are the Predicator (or Head) and  Complement. There are different types of Complement, for example Direct Object, or Predicative Complement.

@Ihavemanyquestions In English, the Subject usually occurs before the verb (apart from in questions). In the present tense verbs in English agree with the Subject. In yes/no questions the subject occurs after thew first tensed verb. You can read a bit about Subjects here and aslo here - scroll to 'Subjects'.

@Ihavemanyquestions Enjoy!

Sorry but -1 for saying "Syntax ≠ Semantics". See my answer.

I think it is best not to migrate this to ELL. Though it may be worth pointing out the correspondence of the [passive] declarative sentence "The door has [now] been fixed" to the interrogative sentence "Has the door been fixed yet?": the subject, in the familiar sentence-initial position, is probably more confidently identified.

Since you're learning German, maybe we should really be using German examples, where the examples are much more clear-cut than in English.
In

Has the tower been built yet?

the subject is tower, even though the tower is the thing that the verb built is acting. However, in

Has he built the tower yet?

the subject is he, even though these sentences mean almost the same thing. But look what happens when we translate them to German (using Google translate).
The first one becomes

Ist der Turm schon gebaut?

and the second

Hat er den Turm schon gebaut?

Der Turn is nominative, as you can see from the article der, which is the masculine nominative definite article, so it must be a subject. Den Turn is accusative, as you can see from the article den, which is the masculine accusative definite article, so you can see it must be an object.
So even if you think the English definition of subject for passive verbs is not intuitive and maybe suspect, this is also the German definition, and because German has cases, we know that these are the right definitions for German.

Yes, in German, the article would tell you what case the noun is in. But if I wanted to translate something from English to German, my problem would be, I have to know what article is used for each noun, by identifying what the subject and objects are. Since the (English) learning resources say to identify them by asking "who?" (nominative) or "whom?" (accusative), I first need to identify the subject and object in the English sentence.

@Ihavemanyquestions: There's a danger in assuming that English grammar is the same as German grammar. In distinguishing the nominative case from the accusative case, the grammars are very similar, but there are lots of times when extrapolating from English to German will lead you astray.

Which of those words d'you truly believe might possibly be the subject, in English or German or any other language?
It should not be necessary to go through the list but since you Asked that Question that way:
How could 'has' be the subject?
How could 'the' be the subject?
How could 'door' be the subject?
How could 'been' be the subject?
How could 'fixed' be the subject?
How could 'yet' be the subject?
Doesn't that boring nonsense leave one and only one Answer - 'door' - as the only possible subject>
If not, can you wholly re-phrase the Question?

In the sentence 'Shut the door,' you'll spend a long time trying to find an overt subject. An assumption has to be made in the above that various types of sentence must contain an overt subject, and that's not at all self-evident. // Not my downvote, though I can see why it might have been given.

@EdwinAshworth I don't understand. How could anything but 'the door' be the subject? How could 'the door' not be  the subject? How could  anything there be more complex?

You're assuming that there must be an overt subject (one that appears), which is not true for some sentences. Try your process of elimination with the sentence 'Shut the door.' There needs to be justification that all standard declarative and interrogative sentences have an overt subject. // The only reason I didn't vote for the question to be migrated to ELL is that tchrist's answer contrasts subject with agent so clearly  (which don't here have the same referent ... in fact, there is no agent mentioned here, as he points out).

Then please, are you suggesting that the unmentioned agent to whom the order is given is the subject?

Before I get to your question in the third paragraph, let me critique your reasoning behind the question in the second paragraph. The idea is that I can indirectly but effectively answer your question by pointing out the core problem with your reasoning leading to the question. So here's your second paragraph:

In the exercises, one sentence says "Has the door been fixed yet?", and the answer says "door" is the subject, but I thought it is the object and that there is no subject in this sentence, because the "door" is, by their description and definition, being "verbed" (it is being "fixed"), and no person who does the fixing is mentioned (ie the subject doing the fixing could be you, me, some third party handyman; whoever it is, they are not mentioned).

The explanation you're trying to apply to the sentence is presented in the first paragraph:

the "subject" is the person or thing (ie a noun) that does the verb, and the "object" is the thing that is "verbed" (or the person or thing that the verb acts on).

Crude as it is, this aptly explains what the subject and object are. But your application is problematic because you erroneously assume that the "verb" in the explanation means a single verb (e.g., fixed) even though there are three verbs in your example sentence:

Has the door been fixed yet?

The meaning of the "verb" in the explanation is supposed to include the collective meaning of all three verbs has been fixed in your example. This collective meaning does include the passive meaning. So, the door is NOT being "verbed". Also, we don't have to mention a person who does the fixing because this sentence isn't about such a person. Therefore, you have no reason to think that the door is the object and that there is no subject in this sentence.
Finally, I respectfully disagree with the quip about Syntax ≠ Semantics by @tchrist because it is based on the same kind of erroneous application of the explanation, as shown here again (from his third paragraph):

You just don't know who the agent responsible for that fixing may have been.

We need not know who the agent responsible for that fixing is, because "fixing" itself is not the action we need to find the agent of, but the whole "being fixed" is the action we need to find the agent of, if you will.
Syntax, by definition, is the study of sentence structures, and the very reason we study sentence structures is to know how different meanings are conveyed using different sentence structures. What's syntax if it cannot be used to explain semantics or is not even related to semantics?

You keep on deciding that people's answers are based on this or that or entail this or that, or imply this and then when they do nothing of the sort! Anyhow, I do not understand from your answer what a subject is, or how you would find it. Lastly, do you really want to claim that syntax=semantics when it comes to subjects?

@Araucaria-Him Please comment on the content of my answer. Why are you being so emotional for nothing? I didn't say "syntax=semantics", I said it's not correct to jump to the conclusion "syntax ≠ semantics" simply because you can't figure out their relationship. Just because you can't doesn't mean it's not there. As far as the OP goes, I think I have presented a persuasive argument as to how the OP can apply their existing knowledge to the sentence at hand and still figure out what the subject is. Again, please critique my answer based on its content, rather than make a blanket statement.

Are you saying that Tchrist couldn't figure out their relationship? (BTW, you put this in your post, therefore it is content). Re the other content: you say that there is a difference between being the agent in relation to being fixed and fixed - could you explain?

@Araucaria-Him That's not what I said. I wouldn't respond from now on unless you ask some specific questions about my answer.

I am struggling to understand your answer, which maybe could be helpfully made clearer for readers. You specifically say that you disagree that Syntax ≠ Semantics, but you don't explain in  what way you disagree! It's also difficult to understand what your post is intended to say when you say that the agent of the fixing and the being fixed are different. It is difficult for us readers to imagine what you might mean? I think the post may benefit from a clear exposition of that point, as it appears to be the central one  in your answer

@Araucaria-Him said you don't explain in what way you disagree! Well, I have written no less than three paragraphs at the end, from the paragraph starting with "Finally". I don't know how much more I should explain. Please read the last three paragraphs. I'm sure you can understand what I'm saying.

@Araucaria-Him OK. At the very least, you agree that we should not be looking for a subject of fixing, don't you? (I should get going, but I will continue to post comments later if you have further questions.)

@JK2 I read your explanation several times and I get what you are saying now. You are saying that this sentence is not in active voice with an agent/grammatical subject doing a verb of fixing, but rather it is a passive voice where it describes the state of being of the door being fixed. From this, I looked up "finding subjects in passive voice" and found this statement on a Miami University website: "In passive voice, the subject of the sentence is not the one doing the action: it will receive the action instead." Now it makes sense since this is a passive voice sentence.

But I am inclined to agree with tchrist and the others, that Syntax ≠ Semantics (in fact, this was the first "D'oh!" moment for me), because everyone knows you can't literally translate things into different languages and still have it mean the same thing or make sense.
Also while I am here: I now see that the statement on Miami University website in my other comment is the same as what Araucaria-Him and Mari-Lou A said previously, I just didn't quite understand and see it at that time.
Thank you everyone!

@Ihavemanyquestions Glad you figured it out. I think one clear upside to my approach is that you can apply what you already have and still understand why the subject is the subject in your sentence without having to learn that the more complex grammar concepts don't really help you except that you have to memorize syntax doesn't help you understand semantics, which sucks. Now, I don't care whose answer you go with. It's your call. But at the very least, their approach has a major drawback that they analyze "fixing" as the verb in the passive sentence, which you know isn't true. Cheers.

Have you thought about the other meaning of the word 'subject', which is similar to 'topic', and denotes the person or thing about which the verb is.  If the verb is active, the subject is doing something to someone or something.  With "The train hit the cow (or cliff) " The train did the hitting, and so is subject to the verb and the cow (or cliff) had the hitting done to it and so is the object.  In the passive, the cow (or cliff) was hit by the train.  So the cow (or cliff) is the subject, while the train is agent. If SHE likes HIM, then HE is liked by HER.
